# Trainer damaging rear tyre

Tags: tire, trainer

I've being using a trainer for a couple of weeks, and apparently it's damaging my tyre:

[image]

As you can see the tyre is "polished", and on top of that I'm seeing small rubber pieces on the floor. The culprit is the tension roller:

[image]

The problem is: the resistance right now is quite low, I just touched the roller on the tyre and then I gave the knob 3 turns. It's not too tight, and even so it's clearly damaging the tyre.

Is this normal? What can I do?

Comment: It’s normal with this type of trainer. Use old tyres or get special trainer tyres.

Comment: ... and the highest permissible pressure as well!

Comment: Open the rear brake calliper as much as possible, like when you want to take out the wheel. The idea is that in no case the brake could be applied when the bike on the trainer, as the roller will grind into the tyre.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wear is normal.  Riding on the road damages your tyre too, but you don't see the wear particles gathered in one spot.

But additionally, riding on a trainer is harsh on a rear tyre and does cause accelerated wear which is what you're seeing here.

It would be common to "use up" any older spare tyres you have around.  There are even specialist trainer-tyres available which are extra hard-wearing and heat tolerant, but would be unsuitable to ride on the road because of very-low grip.

Try riding for a bit, and immediately check the temperature of the tyre - Don't burn yourself though.  You'll be surprised at how hot they get.